# How do I make a class object with templetad array properly?

Tags: c++, class, templates

So I have written a class "Node" in file Node.h as a tree data container. It contains a 2D-array, whose size is given at compile-time, but I can only get it from a different class, not hardtype it. I tried

```
class Node {
    private:
        int array[size][size];
```

which only got me

```
error: ‘fFieldSize’ was not declared in this scope
```

Therefore, I did something like this:

```
template<int T,int Z>
class Node {
    private:
        int array[T][Z];
```

Now, I include this file in my Class "Engine", where I want to

1. use instances of Node
2. use member functions of "Engine" of return type Node

   ```
   1. node<size,size> firstnode;
   2. Node GetData();
   ```

Engine has a .h and a .cxx file.
I can't figure out how to do the thing with the member functions.

I tried

```
Node<size,size> GetData;
```

but I get the error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘MyNAMESPACE::Engine::size’
```

Help would be appreciated. Also, this is my first question, I hope I did everything up to the standards.

Comment: If you *really* want to do this and know the size at compile time, how is your setup different than [something like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dff70a53011900e3) ? Updating your question with a [mcve] of your problem code that we can copy/paste/compile to produce your errors would be helpful.

Comment: Your size variable must be constexpr or literal.

Answer (score 0):

`size` must be either `const` or `constexpr`, as template arguments must be known at compile time.

Otherwise dynamic collection is required, something like:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node(int T,int Z) : array(T,std::vector<int>(Z,0))
        {}

    private:
        vector<vector<int>> array;
```

Comment: I tried making const int size a member variable of Engine, but it still didn't work. As to vectors, I headr arrays are faster/smaller and both size and speed are a concern for my use. Otherwise, i didn't have the whole situation as std::vec can be declared without setting the size, right?

Comment: I find it extremely hard to believe that someone who's just starting in on C++ has any idea of how fast or slow vectors would be compared to arrays. My advice is to drop your preconceived notions and go with a std::vector<std::vector<int>>.

Comment: You are right that I don't know much about the actual speed difference, I do know however that my task has a limited time of 1s and has to do as many computations as possible. To be specific I try to implement a Monte Carlo Tree Search.

Comment: If you are hellbent on using an Array, use dynamic allocation. Pass the size in your constructor, make your array be of type int** and assign with new int*[count], allocating each element in a loop.

Comment: a vector will be optimized so fast that you won't even see a difference with or without it.